# Someone explain why the ambiguity here, please?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

`Fill<T, Pack, Size, Value>` is to be the type `Pack<Value, Value, ..., Value>`, where Value is repeated Size times.  Can someone explain, why this is ambiguous?

```
template <typename T, template <T...> class Pack, int Size, int Count, typename Output, T Value>
struct FillHelper;

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, int Size, int Count, T... Output, T Value>
struct FillHelper<T, P, Size, Count, P<Output...>, Value> :
    FillHelper<T, P, Size, Count + 1, P<Output..., Value>, Value> {};

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, int Size, T... Output, T Value>
struct FillHelper<T, P, Size, Size, P<Output...>, Value> {
    using type = P<Output...>;
};

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, int Size, T Value>
using Fill = typename FillHelper<T, P, Size, 0, P<>, Value>::type;

template <int...> struct Pack;

int main() {
    using T = Fill<int, Pack, 10, 4>;
}
```

while this is not:

```
template <typename T, int Size, int Count, typename Output, T Value>
struct FillHelper;

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, int Size, int Count, T... Output, T Value>
struct FillHelper<T, Size, Count, P<Output...>, Value> :
    FillHelper<T, Size, Count + 1, P<Output..., Value>, Value> {};

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, int Size, T... Output, T Value>
struct FillHelper<T, Size, Size, P<Output...>, Value> {
    using type = P<Output...>;
};

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, int Size, T Value>
using Fill = typename FillHelper<T, Size, 0, P<>, Value>::type;

template <int...> struct Pack;

int main() {
    using T = Fill<int, Pack, 10, 4>;
}
```

It turns out that I indirectly noticed that the second is shorter and thus better than the first, but I was baffled why the first one would not compile.
I get error with GCC 4.9.2, which is very recent. Error with Visual Studio 2013 too. 
A better solution than the second code is welcomed, by the way.

**Update:**  Reducing the problem further, it turns out that the presence of the template-template in the specializations is NOT the problem, because this DOES compile with GCC 4.9.2 (and Visual Studio 2013 too):

```
template <typename T, template <T...> class Pack, int Size, int Count>
struct F;

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, int Size, int Count>
struct F : F<T, P, Size, Count + 1> {};

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, int Size>
struct F<T, P, Size, Size> {
    using type = int;
};

template <int...> struct Pack;

int main() {
    using T = F<int, Pack, 10, 0>::type;
}
```

So what exactly is the problem in the first code that is causing confusion with GCC and VS?

Comment: Fwiw, clang 3.6 munches down the first one without error. Info: Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn). Maybe include your toolchain info.

Comment: I get error with GCC 4.9.2, which is very recent.  Error with Visual Studio 2013 too.

Comment: Well, clang is apparently smarter than we are, as it realizes non of this is actually *used*. Adding `T t;` to `main()` delivers a dose of: main.cpp:23:7: Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Pack<4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4>'. Though that may be useful to know regardless. **edit** nm. adding `{};` after `Pack`  and it once-again compiles.

Comment: My money is on a bug in GCC's partial specialization ordering algorithm. I searched known bugs but couldn't find anything. You might want to consider reporting it.

Comment: @Brian, perhaps my third example updated in my question sheds more light on whether GCC is actually bugged or not?  The third example, which seems to have the same symptoms as the first one, DOES compile.

Comment: Maybe it's the simultaneous presence of `typename T` and `template <T...> class`.

Comment: @Brian.  Nope, I updated the third example with that too.  That also compiles.  Cannot figure out what it is exactly that's causing the problem.

Comment: Maybe you should just report the bug to GCC.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why gcc rejects your code, but if you have C++14 support, a less tedious solution is to use `std::make_index_sequence` to construct a pack with `Size` elements, then deduce the pack and expand it again, like so:

```
template <typename T, template <T...> class Pack, T Value, size_t... indices>
auto FillHelper(std::index_sequence<indices...>) -> Pack<(indices, Value)...>;

template <typename T, template <T...> class P, int Size, T Value>
using Fill = decltype(FillHelper<T, P, Value>(std::make_index_sequence<Size>()));
```

Link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7771560a1f32461d

Comment: Nice!  I never thought of using the comma operator.  Since it is just a dummy operator here, I guess any index_sequence of length `Size` would work.